# pouchdb has stopped syncing with no errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pouchdb

I am using this sync code that did work and now does not sync with no errors.

```
this.sync = function(remoteDatabase) {
            database.sync(remoteDatabase, {live: true, retry: true})
                .on('complete', function (changes) {
                  // yay, we're in sync!
                    console.log("sync complete");
                }).on('change', function (change) {
                    // yo, something changed!
                    console.log("sync change");
                }).on('paused', function (info) {
                  // replication was paused, usually because of a lost connection
                    console.log("sync pause");
                }).on('active', function (info) {
                  // replication was resumed
                    console.log("sync active");
                }).on('error', function (err) {
                  // boo, we hit an error!
                    console.log("sync error");
                  alert("data was not replicated to server, error - " + err);
            });
            console.log("end of sync function");
        };
```

my dev console shows:

```
        end of sync Function
```

After about 10 seconds the console shows:

```
        sync paused
        sync paused
```

No errors in console, including no indications of syncing.

My google search came up with nothing similar.

Any ideas would be great.

Comment: You've got the answer right there, don't you? It will display `sync pause` "usually because of a lost connection." You probably are not able to connect to your remote database right now. That could be something as simple as the router has been turned off to full-on catastrophic blow-up on the database side. Impossible to say from here.

Comment: i am on a desktop wired to the network server. what could be reasons it lost connections?

Comment: Like I said, plenty. Computer is dead, someone unplugged the server from the network, it's rebooting, your firewall is blocking it, the servers firewall is blocking you, etc. etc. etc.

Comment: thank you for the info, I have restarted my sync gateway for couchbase and i get errors on my dev console. I will research further. thanks again

Comment: mike, are you familiar with Couchbase sync gateway? i am wondering if my config file "configServer" should match my sync database in puochdb?

Comment: I'm not familiar, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem.
I was toying with offline capabilities and did not clear cache. there were upup.sw.min.js files in cache that seem to be gumming up everything. after clearing cache for that address my syncing works.

Thanks Mike for pushing me to look further.